# Entity Framework not saving all the information into database

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm facing a problem which one I tried some solutions to solve, but I couldn't. 
Basically, I have a method which I receive as parameter one string and one serialized Map from ajax post.
Everything regarding this is working really well, except the fact when I have for example the same **FileId** with different **UseCaseId**, because then just one information is being saved, not both.

**UseCaseId and FileId ** are foreign keys from other tables.

**The relationship:**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
        .HasIndex(ct => ct.FileId)
        .IsUnique(false);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
        .HasIndex(ct => ct.UseCaseId)
        .IsUnique(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
        .HasKey(cn => cn.ContentId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
        .HasOne(cn => cn.File)
        .WithOne()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
        .HasOne(cn => cn.UseCase)
        .WithOne()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

In the follow example, two elements, exactly the same with just a different **UseCase** , need to be saved, but only the last one is saved in the database.

[Contents variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3gJw.png)

[Database - Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO0vi.png)

**Parameter received:**

[Parameter Received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6xIm.png)

This is the code where the problem occurs:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Create([FromBody] ContentJson data)
{
    List<Content> contents = new List<Content>();
    var contentName = string.Empty;
    var array = data.content;
    int order;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
    {
        var files = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(array[i][1].ToString());

        if (files == null || files.Length == 0)
            continue;

        contentName = array[i][0].ToString();
        order = 1;

        foreach(var fileName in files)
        {
            Content content = new Content();    
            content.Order = order;
            content.UseCaseId = long.Parse(contentName);
            content.FileId = unitOfWork.FileRepository.Get(f => f.FileName.Equals(fileName)).First().FileId;
            contents.Add(content);
            order++;
        }
    }

    unitOfWork.ContentRepository.AddRange(contents);
    unitOfWork.Save();

    return Json(Ok());
}
```

- The **ContentId** is automatically generated.
- EntityFramework and Dotnet in the latest version
- I've already tried to save on each iteration.
- Tried to implement Equals and HashCode,

  ```
  public void Save()
  {
      context.SaveChanges();
  }

  private bool disposed = false;

  protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
      if (!disposed)
      {
          if (disposing)
          {
              context.Dispose();
          }
      }
      disposed = true;
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
      Dispose(true);
      GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }



  public Repository<Content> ContentRepository
  {
      get
      {
          if(contentRepository == null)
          {
              contentRepository = new Repository<Content>(context);
          }
          return contentRepository;
      }
  }
  ```

Could anyone help me, please ? I got stuck on this problem.

Comment: Share `unitOfWork.Save();` code.

Comment: I've added the UnitOfWork as well

Comment: @JoseAguiar the DbContext *is* a UoW. DbSet *is* a Repository. Adding a "generic" repository only introduces problems by trying to force a low-level concept on top of a higher-level abstraction. Notice how those code you posted here, even the Dispose implementation, does nothing more than delegate to the context.

Comment: EF Core has no problem saving multiple items to the database. The code posted here though uses something else, some `Repository` class whose `AddRange` or `Add` methods are missing.

Comment: Or it could be that the *data input* is wrong - the code takes a strongly typed object, converts it to string then tries to parse it as JSON. This would only work if the original object was a simple string. Why not just use as-is then? Could this string contain duplicates? Or only a single item?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I wrote the code without the UoW and it worked ! I didn't know that it could cause some problems like that ! Thank you very much ! But the strange fact is that it works for every case, like to save and to query simple information, except in this case.

Comment: Check Gunnar Peipman's [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have conflicting FK configuration.

`IsUnique(false)` here

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
    .HasIndex(ct => ct.FileId)
    .IsUnique(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
    .HasIndex(ct => ct.UseCaseId)
    .IsUnique(false);
```

implies that the FKs are not unique, but then `WithOne()` here

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
    .HasOne(cn => cn.File)
    .WithOne()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
    .HasOne(cn => cn.UseCase)
    .WithOne()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

implies that they are unique (the only difference between one-to-many and one-to-one FK relationships in relational databases is that the later FK is backed with unique constraint/index). And this takes precedence over non unique index mapping and is causing the issue.

Since you want them to be non unique, you have to change the relationships to be one-to-many (or many-to-one depending on which side you are looking at) by replacing in both places `WithOne()` with `WithMany()`.

Once you do that, you could remove both `HasIndex` configurations because they will be automatically created for you by EF Core conventions. In fact they would have been created with your fluent configuration as well, but as unique. Probably that's what you were trying to fix with these `HasIndex` statements, but that's simply the wrong place and instead you should fix the what is causing it.

Comment: It solved the problem ! Thank you very much. I've just changed the line "With One" to "With Many in both cases, deleted the "Has Index" part, and everything worked perfect ! Thank you very much again !

Answer (score 0):

In place of  contentName use fileName.contentName
i.e   content.UseCaseId = long.Parse(fileName.contentName);
and same applies to fileId